# the origin of the differential of Spectral Sequence?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

I'm wondering why the differential in homological Spectral Sequences $(E^*_{p,q},d^r)$ is defined as;
$d^r_{p,q}: E^{r}_{p,q} \rightarrow E^{r}_{p-r,q+r-1}$ .

From Weibel's homological algebra(p122), or in any other texts, I don't see how/why Koszul or Leray defined the differential in that way.  Are there any deep geometric meaning/mathematical techniques for that matter?

Comment: It's defined like that because that's what comes up in the concrete examples you want to study.

Comment: It's difficult to answer such a vague question. The only solution, to get more intuition, is to keep studying spectral sequences from lots of different sources and with lots of examples. This [note by Chow](http://www.ams.org/notices/200601/fea-chow.pdf) is not a bad piece to add to the list.

Comment: To follow up on @IgorKhavkine's comment: _what kind of explanation_ are you looking for? What kind of answer would make you go "now I see how/why Koszul or Leray defined the differential"? Are you asking about the indexing? Are you asking what spectral sequences are meant for? etc.

Comment: One origin of the spectral sequence is Wei's proof of De Rham theorem, for which he used the Cech-De Rham complex. If you chase the zig-zag route from down-right to upper-left, it is equivalent to chase through various differentials in the spectral sequence. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: For a reference, I think you can check Sternberg's lecture notes on differential geometry: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1301985.files/2301304.pdf

Comment: There is a book by Stephen Shatz in which he discusses  spectral sequences.  He makes the point that a spectral sequence is a way to compute the cohomology of a graded complex from the cohomology of the grades.  From that point of view, the differentials are (imho) very natural.

Comment: SeWon, you can vote to reopen your question by clicking on the  fourth button in the row of buttons "share cite edit reopen (2) flag" right under your question.